# Make top of view to be before end of other view ConstraintLayout

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

I want to achieve A UI where I have Two views **VIEW1**, **VIEW2** with these *constraints*

1. VIEW1 has height of `wrap_content`
2. VIEW2 should `it's top` to be before end of VIEW1 with 10dp for example.

[Final UI i want with Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zNzo5.png)

Comment: Post your code.

Comment: I added them UI + code

Comment: please add code here so someone take your code and update it

Comment: Add code here do not add images.

Comment: @MahmoudMabrouk : What you need. Pls Draw it i will upload code

Comment: You want same as UI Image?

Comment: @MahmoudMabrouk : I have added answer please let me know you want same like that?

Comment: @ShwetaChauhan I added comment to your answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you know, setting `layout_marginTop="-10dp"` will not work too.

You can try setting `translationY="-10dp"` to VIEW2 then it will work.

Comment: It solved the problem at top of VIEW2  but make  VIEW2'end(bottom) wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution by using

> a view with fixed height that equal to how many dp VIEW2 should start before end of VIEW1.

full code(also has same ending corners to bottom) ::

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/mainContent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="@color/faded_orange"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:translationY="0dp"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/space"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/space2"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/space" />

    <Space
        android:id="@+id/space"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/topLayout"
        />

    <Space
        android:id="@+id/space2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/bottomLayout"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/topLayout"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/_100sdp"
        android:background="@drawable/header_bg"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/bottomLayout"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/_100sdp"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_bottom_view"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]

You can do something like this.

- A Top View ( View 1 ) with constraints of top, start and end of parent.
- A Bottom ( View 2 ) with constraints topToBottomOf = View 1.
- Add a rounded rectangle ( View 3 ) with topToBottomOf = View 1 and height = 10dp or whatever the overlap height you want to have.

Comment: rounded corners is included in view 1 at design requirements

Comment: Divide View 1 from your design into a Rectangle and a rounded rectangle with bottom and right corner radius set (View 3) in my screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

> As I understand you want view same as you added UI Image. This UI can be achieved using Guideline.

[image]

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview9"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/_100sdp"
        android:background="@color/bg_counter"
        android:text="textview"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.13" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview10"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/_80sdp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        android:text="textview"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/guideline" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: for first view it is fixed at your code `android:layout_height="@dimen/_100sdp"`
that is not as i want, it should be wrap_content